# Why is my A* object resetting to (0, 0, 0), instead of following its path?

Tags: unity, c#, path-finding

I'm working on an RTS project, and I'd like to use the [A* Project by Aron Granberg](http://arongranberg.com/astar/) to navigate around obstacles. The problem is that the correct path is displayed in the scene, the unit is still walking forwards, but the unit just jumps to (0, 0, 0). As is, this as a workaround to have some progress in my build script.

[image]

Why is my A* object resetting to (0, 0, 0), instead of following its path?

---

I don't know where I made the mistake that leads to this behavior. Here is script responsible for the movement:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Pathfinding;
using RTS;

public class Unit : WorldObject
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Path path;
    public float nextWaypointDistance = 3;

    private int currentWaypoint = 0;

    protected override void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dir = (path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] - transform.position).normalized;

        MakeMove(dir);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint])
            < nextWaypointDistance)
        {
            currentWaypoint++;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void MakeMove(Vector3 dir)
    {
        transform.position 
            = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, dir, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the distance between two points of your grid? Is it less than 3.0?

Comment: I am removing a lot of the code from this question; most of it is irrelevant, especially given that I was able to identify the problem using the current excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your providing a normalised direction as the second parameter for `Vector3.MoveTowards()`, where the second parameter is *suppose* to be the target coordinates. As you have already found out, supplying *target* instead of *direction* fixes your problem.

---

Let's take a look at the [API resource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html).

> ## Vector3.MoveTowards
>
> public static Vector3 **MoveTowards**(Vector3 **current**, Vector3 **target**, float **maxDistanceDelta**);
>
> **...**
>
> ### Description
>
> Moves a point current in a straight line towards a target point.
> **The value returned by this function is a point `maxDistanceDelta` units closer to a target/ point along a line *between* `current` and `target`.**
>
> **...**
> <sub>[- Unity API: Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found:

Changing   `Vector3 dir = (path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] - transform.position).normalized;` to   `Vector3 dir = path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] worked.`

But I still have no clue, why.